# Why am I getting MySQL error 1064 on foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_1 (
    EMP_NUM varchar(3),
    EMP_LNAME varchar(15),
    EMP_FNAME varchar(15),
    EMP_INITIAL varchar(1),
    EMP_HIREDATE datetime,
    JOB_CODE varchar(3), FOREIGN KEY (JOB_CODE) REFERENCES JOB
);
```

This is the code that is given to create a table that is a subset of another table. It is part of an exercise.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' REFERENCES JOB)' at line 8

Is the error message that is output in PHPMyAdmin when the query is run.

Where is the syntax off on line 8? After checking w3 schools, and textbook, I cannot see the problem.

Answer (score 3):

you're missing the referencing foreign key column on the `JOB` table

so it should be something like

```
FOREIGN KEY (JOB_CODE) REFERENCES JOB(job_code_col)
```

so if your `JOB` table also has a column called `JOB_CODE`, then the DDL would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_1 (
    EMP_NUM varchar(3),
    EMP_LNAME varchar(15),
    EMP_FNAME varchar(15),
    EMP_INITIAL varchar(1),
    EMP_HIREDATE datetime,
    JOB_CODE varchar(3), FOREIGN KEY (JOB_CODE) REFERENCES JOB (JOB_CODE)
);
```

Comment: I do have the JOB_CODE column in the Job Table. Does it need to be set as foreign key in the Job Table first before the query can run? I am not fully following you.

Comment: you need to add the name of that column inside parentheses following the table name, look at my answer where I added `(job_code_col)`, that should be the name of the column on the `JOB` table

Comment: @mango762, I updated my answer explicitly since you said you have a `JOB_CODE` column on the `JOB` table

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Í¾' at line 8 is till being returned when the query is entered. Not sure what the 'Í¾' refers to, but I do indeed have JOB_CODE column in JOB table.

Comment: @mango762 you've copy-pasted some bad encoding from somewhere. where in your query do you see `Í¾`?

Comment: You are correct on it being an encoding error, I feel silly that I didn't catch that. It was a bad copy-paste. Thank you.